# Wrap HTML & PHP in PHP

Tags: php

I'm struggling to find a way to wrap HTML and PHP within a PHP IF statement.

```
<div class="preview">
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <?php if ( get_post_gallery() ) : ?>
                            <?php echo "Heres a preview of the private gallery, please login to view more."; ?>
                            <?php echo get_post_gallery(); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </div>
```

Inside

```
<?php if ( post_password_required() ) {

                    the_content();
                    } else {

                    } ?>
```

So replace the_content() with the "preview" code.

I have tried this,b ut it doesn't seem to work.

```
<?php if ( post_password_required() ) {

                    echo '<div class="preview">'
                        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                        if ( get_post_gallery() ) :
                             echo "Heres a preview of the private gallery, please login to view more.";
                             echo get_post_gallery();
                        endif;
                    endwhile;
                    echo '</div>'

                    } else {

                    } ?>
```

Comment: This is pretty much what PHP is designed to do.  Have you tried reading the manual?

Comment: well, you're missing some semicolons so your code wont run, google php error reporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried? here's an example:

```
<?php if ( post_password_required() ): ?>
    <div class="preview">
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php if ( get_post_gallery() ) : ?>
            <p>Heres a preview of the private gallery, please login to view more.</p>
            <?php echo get_post_gallery(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I'd point out also that PHP should not wrap HTML that is not dynamic (see andrew's answer). The "Here's a preview" text can have the PHP tags and `echo` stripped.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ( post_password_required() ) {

                    the_content();
                    } else {  //just close the php tags here ?>

          <p> preview content goes here </p>

                  <?php //and re open them here
                     }  
                   ?>
```